# How to create an all-around night sky in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, world

So I created a night sky following this video https://youtu.be/9vbq6HOgA2w 
It was going pretty well until I noticed that only half of the world actually looks decent. The bottom half/ middle is this plain ugly color I want to get rid of but I'm not exactly sure how I would do that.

[image]

Comment: In the video,he use the sky texture node as a base,which create this sort of effect,instead you can use a solid color as a base.

Comment: In the beginning he added Mapping node which allows moving texture coordinates by some axis, and he used that for changing location of horizon by Z axis.

Comment: Usually, the bottom half is invisible if your scene has a ground. So, this is kind of ok.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use an HDRI from NASA's [SVS: Deep Star Maps](https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/4851).

You can get a full sphere OpenEXR image in 4k that is very usable, or you can get 8, 16, or even 32k versions.

Here's my world shader for using HDRIs.  It allows you to rotate the map as you need.

[image: World shader for using HDRIs]

Just download the NASA maps, replace your world shader with something like mine, and plug the OpenEXR image into the image node.