# I cannot get my glass window to render with tree background no matter what tutorial I try

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, glass

[image][image]My glass windows continued to render as a black solid instead of transparent as I can view it in material view and rendered view prior to rendering the whole scene.  I have tried numerous tutorials for glass.  I cannot render in Cycles as my pc cannot handle the render and almost closes/ freezes the program for an extended period of time.  I am in Eevee.[image]

[image]

Comment: wanted to post more images but couldn't figure out how.

Comment: To add images, edit your answer, and select the position where you want the next image to go.  Type CTRL-G to bring up the menu for adding the image.  In EEVEE you need to change the glass material's blend mode to alpha blend or alpha hash.

Comment: @MartyFouts thank you for assistance with adding images.  I have alpha blend in my glass material.  These are some of the settings I have updated through tutorials, this is how they are set now.

Comment: can you share your blend file in your question? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: @MartyFouts Yes I added the blend file

Comment: @MartyFouts Oh my gosh thank you so much! Is there a simple way to make the background image more clear/ make a different part of it visible through the window? in particular the tree

Comment: [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/237791/42221) has a diagram of a world shader that you can adjust the location of.  Use the _Mapping_ node's _Z Rotation_ to rotate the position of the world image.  Don't change anything else in the mapping node or it will distort the world image.  You can make it brighter by changing the strength value in the _background_ node.

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be your world shader.  If you go to the Shader workspace and change the Shader type from *Object* to *World*  You will see that you have a world shader that looks like this:

[image: World shader]

The World shader should be a *Background*  shader:

[image: Corrected World shader]

When I make that change, your image renders with the background visible through the window.